# Multiple SliverAppBar in a CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I require to have multiple SliverAppBar, each with its own SliverList in a single view.  Currently only the first SliverAppBar is responding correctly.

I have of course, done extended searching on SO and Google, but have not found a solution yet!

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Details'),
        ),
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            new SliverAppBar(
              floating: true,
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              title: Text('1'),
            ),
            new SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text('Text 1')),
                childCount: 20,
              ),
            ),
            new SliverAppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              title: Text('2'),
              floating: true,
            ),
            new SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text('Text 2')),
                childCount: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
  }
```

If you do scroll, I expect to see the title "2" floating as well, when you are scrolling the list.

Comment: You should try one of these:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sticky_headers#-readme-tab-
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_sticky_header#-readme-tab-

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I think your question is relevant. I'll answer it properly so it can be useful to other people, OK?

Comment: I have developed a package designed to address this particular issue. Navigate to the final section. https://pub.dev/packages/widget_visibility_checker

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a limitation of `CustomScrollView`. It's possible to work around that, but it's very tricky, unless you have fixed-height items and fixed-length lists. If so, you can assume the height of your whole session (`AppBar` height + height of each list item).

Take a look:

```dart
class Foo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FooState createState() => _FooState();
}

class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  static const double listItemHeight = 50;
  static const int listItemCount = 15;

  static const double sessionHeight = kToolbarHeight + (listItemCount * listItemHeight);

  int floatingAppBarIndex;
  ScrollController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    floatingAppBarIndex = 0;
    controller = ScrollController()..addListener(onScroll);
  }

  void onScroll() {
    double scrollOffset = controller.offset;
    int sessionsScrolled = 0;

    while (scrollOffset > sessionHeight) {
      scrollOffset -= sessionHeight;
      sessionsScrolled++;
    }

    if (sessionsScrolled != floatingAppBarIndex) {
      setState(() {
        floatingAppBarIndex = sessionsScrolled;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Details'),
      ),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: controller,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          new SliverAppBar(
            floating: floatingAppBarIndex == 0,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            title: Text('1'),
          ),
          new SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                return SizedBox(
                  height: listItemHeight,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text('Text 1'),
                  ),
                );
              },
              childCount: listItemCount,
            ),
          ),
          new SliverAppBar(
            floating: floatingAppBarIndex == 1,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            title: Text('2'),
          ),
          new SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                return SizedBox(
                  height: listItemHeight,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text('Text 2'),
                  ),
                );
              },
              childCount: listItemCount,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As I said, you're still able to do that in a list with variable values (item height and list length), but it would be very very tricky. If this is your case, I recommend using one of these plugins:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sticky_headers
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_sticky_header